# Symfony upgrade from 4.1 to 4.4 authenticationutils servicelocator

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am trying upgrade Symfony application from 4.1 to 4.4 and I have error in authentication in SecurityController I have

```
public function loginAction (Request $request)
    {
        /* var AuthenticationUtils $authUtils */
        $authUtils= $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('admin/user/login.html.twig', array(
            'error'         => $error,
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        ));
    }
```

but after upgrade I have this error
[image]

how I may solve this error?

Comment: You should use [constructor injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#constructor-injection) or [inject the service into the controller action](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#controller-accessing-services)

Comment: Just for info, you are getting this error because you changed from Controller to AbstractController for your base controller class.  Expect to see this sort of error anytime you use $this->get().  You can stay with the original Controller class if you want.  Just means you can't upgrade to 5.x.

Comment: As usual, please share all error messages in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. As far as I see, the error contains a pretty obvious hint about how to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..as mentioned by @dbrunmann

```php
public function loginAction (Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {        
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('admin/user/login.html.twig', array(
            'error'         => $error,
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        ));
    }
```

Use `php bon\console debug:autowiring <some_service_name>` - to find out which typhint to use to get the right service

E.g. `php bin\console debug:autowiring utils` will give you

[image]